# JLabel multiline with escape for HTML tags to display

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, multiline

I want to add multiline label in the panel.

```
jLabelTagInfo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabelTagInfo.setText("Replace the tags <italic></italic> with <name content-type=\"names\"></name>");
```

But the Label looks like

[image]

It goes out of Panel.

When I use HTML tags in it, the tags are gone:

```
jLabelTagInfo.setText("<html>Replace the tags <italic></italic> with <br><name content-type=\"names\"></name></html>");
```

[image]

How to escape tags so that it will display in `JLabel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<italic></italic>
```

To the [HTML entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```
&lt;italic&gt;&lt;/italic&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to display multiline text in JLabel without HTML tags.
See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html): 'A display area for a short text string...'.

You can use non-editable [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) instead.

Comment: You don't escape the tags, you just represent them with HTML entity characters.